# Composer update

Tags: updating, composer

I had an existing Drupal 7 website already running. I downloaded a template composer.json file https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/blob/7.x/composer.json , to be able to run composer update. It updates modules perfectly, however when it came to drupal core it does not update (drupal 7.59 -> 7.6). The path it currently has is

```
"installer-paths": {
        "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
```

but (the website I got composer.json file from) definition of web directory was for their instance:

"Drupal will be installed in the web-directory."

So my installer path is core/ and it still does not get updated. My question is how can i find out which directory drupal-core should be updating? If it is root, I have tried "./:[type..]", "core:[type..]", "web:[type..]" to no avail. Any pointers would help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> So my installer path is core/

Assuming by that you mean the Drupal installation is in ./core/, as relative to your Composer project root (i.e. /path/to/core/index.php etc. exist), then your installed path should simply be "core":

```
"installer-paths": {
    "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
```

Comment: So I followed these steps, composer update, did a update db through the gui (used drush last time), and all my modules got updated. Except I still see a warning on `admin/modules/update` about core. In my core/CHANGELOG.txt I see 7.60, but the update is telling me I am still on 7.59

Comment: Clear the cache and try again. And check you’ve run it in the right folder, the parent folder of your Drupal installation

Comment: By parent folder of your Drupal installation, could you clarify a bit more. I have root: -Install.txt -CHANGELOG.txt -sites/ -core. Inside core, I have it's own -CHANGELOG.txt -Install.txt sites/ etc.

Comment: So I see that my problem is all my core files are spread out in the root directory. When I move them into core/ and update core, I get `The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.` because I changed the path of my core files.